# Menu reduce space between words

Tags: css

Need to make the space between the words (height) smaller in css
Theme twenty thirteen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply line-height on the menu `<li>`, or `<a>`. You can use the dev tools to see the changes.

Comment: NO HELP _ don't understand - no idea where, how to do it. No help at all. What is a dev tool?. I just need instruction on HOW & where to change the css file not geek stiuff